# Can a vampire attack twice with their claws using Multiattack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, undead, multiattack

In *Monster Manual* p. 295-298, it talks about PCs becoming Vampires. The [Vampire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire) stat block says:

> ***Multiattack.*** The vampire makes two attacks, only one of which can be a bite attack.

(The [Vampire Spawn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire-spawn) has the same Multiattack action.)

Because of the word "can", would it be possible to assume that it also could choose not to? Specifically, for the multiattack, could the Vampire just use their claws twice instead of one claw and one bite?

It looks like they can't bite twice because "only one" can be a bite, but it doesn't comment on the claws.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you referring to the [vampire spawn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire-spawn) monster? I ask because the full-fledged vampire lacks a claw attack, instead having an unarmed strike attack. Also, feel free to take the [tour] if you have a chance. Happy gaming!

Comment: Actually both, because they both have the same multiattack description. THANKS COMMUNITY!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 18):

### Yes, they can make two of the same attack

As you intuit, the use of *can* means the option for a vampire is either...

- 2 unarmed strike attacks (claws for vampire spawn)
- 1 bite, 1 unarmed strike attack

The inclusion of that clause is to remove the option of...

- 2 bite attacks

> **only one** of which can be a bite attack. [**emphasis** mine]

Answer (score 5):

### You're right

The vampires multiattack action limits it to making (at most) one bite attack, but the others (one or two, depending) can be any other attack it has available, including claws as well as any weapons it is equipped with, in any combination.